# Big-O small clarification

Tags: c, big-o, time-complexity

Is `O(log(log(n)))` actually just `O(log(n))` when it comes to time complexity?
Do you agree that this function `g()` has a time complexity of `O(log(log(n)))`?

```
int f(int n) {
    if (n <= 1)
        return 0;
    return f(n/2) + 1;
}

int g(int n) {
    int m = f(f(n));
    int i;
    int x = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        x += i * i;
    }
    return m;
}
```

Comment: `O(log log n)` is `O(log n)` but not the other way around.

Comment: @PålGD Do you mean they are actually the same, or that O(log n) is an upper bound for O(log(log(n)))?

Comment: The use of _is_ in [Landau notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) refers to class membership, or in this case, class containment.  The class of all functions in `O(log log n)` is a subclass of the `O(log n)`.  But you can also say that `log n` is an upper bound of `log n`, yes.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

function `f(n)` computes the logarithm in base `2` of `n` by repeatedly dividing by `2`.  It iterates **log<sub>2</sub>(n)** times.

Calling it on its own result will indeed return **log<sub>2</sub>(log<sub>2</sub>(n))** for an **additional** **log<sub>2</sub>(log<sub>2</sub>(n))** iterations.
So far the complexity is **O(log(N)) + O(log(log(N))**.  The first term dominates the second, overall complexity is **O(log(N))**.

The final loop iterates **log<sub>2</sub>(log<sub>2</sub>(n))** times, time complexity of this last phase is **O(log(log(N))**, negligible in front of the initial phase.

Note that since `x` is not used before the end of function `g`, computing it is not needed and the compiler may well optimize this loop to nothing.

Overall time complexity comes out as **O(log(N))**, which is **not** the same as O(log(log(N)).

Comment: So when it comes to function composition you seperate the time complexity of each and add them, not multiply them?

Comment: @SomeoneWithAQuestion: for simple cases like this, if you can compute the number of operations for a phase, this gives the time complexity.  You then add the complexity of separate phases, and simplify by keeping only the most significant term.

Comment: I would note that while O(log N) is not equivalent to O(log log N), an O(log log N) function is also an O(log N) function (the O bound does not have to be tight).

Answer (score 7):

Looks like it is `log(n) + log(log n) + log(log n)`.

In order: the first recursion of `f()`, plus the second recursion of `f()`, and the for loop, so the final complexity is O(log n), because lower order terms are ignored.

Comment: Where did the first log n came from?

Comment: @SomeoneWithAQuestion The first recursion in f().

Answer (score 3):

```
int f(int n) {
    if (n<=1)
        return 0;
    return f(n/2) + 1;
}
```

Has Time Complexity of Order `O(log2(n))`. Here 2 is base of logrithm.

```
int g(int n) {
    int m = f(f(n)); // O(log2(log2(n))
    int i, x=0;
    for( i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        x += i*i;
    }
    // This for loop will take O(log2(log2(n))
   return m;
}
```

Hence overall time complexity of given function is :
`T(n) = t1 + t2 + t3`

But here `O(log2(n))` dominates over `O(log2(log2(n))`.

Hence time complexity of given function is `log2(n)`.

Please read [What is a plain English explanation of "Big O" notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/plain-english-explanation-of-big-o) once.

Comment: O(log2(n)) is exactly the same as O(log n), there's no need to write it like that.

Answer (score 1):

The time consumed by O(log n) algorithms depends only linearly on the number of digits of n. So it is very easy to scale it.

Say you want to compute F(100000000), the 10^8th F....ascci number. For a O(log n) algorithm it is only going to take 4x the time consumed by computing F(100).

O(log log n) terms can show up in a variety of different places, but there are typically two main routes that will arrive at this runtime. Reference link enter code here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16472012/what-would-cause-an-algorithm-to-have-olog-log-n-complexity).

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question.