# Big O Notation for simple loop

Tags: big-o

I am just starting out in a data structure class, and the instructors have posted 10 problems and asked the Big O of one of them.  Based off the posts I have read I am assuming that the Big O of this code would be O(1), since the data parameter is a single data element.  However, it does execute multiple times depending on the size of the number so would that make it O(N)?

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        f(100000);
    }

    public static long f (int n) {
        long sum = 0;
        for (long i = 2; i < n; i = i * i) {
            sum += i;
            System.out.println(sum);
        }
        return sum;
    } // end f
}
```

Comment: look at the expression `i = i * i` that should give you a clue.

Comment: [HINT]: Think about what is the effect of squaring the `i` counter is doing to the complexity i.e. how is the number of loop iterations related to `N`.

Comment: Print `i` instead of `sum` to get a sense of how this plays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function has a time complexity of **O(log(log(n))**.

`i` grows by multiplication in an exponentially growing factor, so that's "double exponential growth" (not sure if that's a valid definition), and the complexity is the inverse. You can read more about this class of complexity [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16472012/what-would-cause-an-algorithm-to-have-olog-log-n-complexity).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, and the link.  Unfortunately, I don't have enough points to vote the answer as useful.

Comment: @Vaughnjavier don't worry about it, others can vote if they find this helpful.

Answer (score 1):

### Analyzing your algorithm using Sigma notation

To rigorously analyze the growth of your algorithm, you can use Sigma notation as follows:

[image]

with:

[image]

where we've also assumed, in the equality using the result from `(*)`, that `n` is not a number on the form `2^(2^j)`, for some positive integer `j`. For values of `n` where this assumption does not hold, just remove the [floor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) in the sum over `k` above.

---

### Result: log-logaritmic time complexity

From the above, it's apparent that your algorithm has a **log-logarithmic** time complexity, namely (asymptotic upper bound) `O(log(log n))`.