# Solving T(n) = 2T(n^(1/2)) + 1 asymptotically using a recursion tree?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, recurrence

I need to solve the recurrence

> T(n) = 2T(n<sup>1/2</sup>) + 1

I need to find the asymptotic time complexity. I'm using the recursion tree method but I'm getting stuck. I know the answer is Θ(log n), but I'm not sure how to arrive at this. How do you solve this recurrence?

Comment: yes             the recurrence is what you said !

Comment: What's the stop clause?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question, and actually belongs on [Mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/), not Stack Overflow.

Comment: @MichaelGaskill I think this belongs here, but if it didn't, it would belong on CS, not Mathematics.

Comment: @intboolstring I agree with your suggestion of [Computer Science](http://cs.stackexchange.com), but I think it really is off-topic for Stack Overflow.  If you read the [tour](/tour), there's nothing about this question that is suited to SO.

Comment: @MichaelGaskill Alright.  If you believe that asking about recurrence relationships is off-topic for Stack Overflow, I would suggest making a meta [tag:burninate-request] for [tag:recurrence-relation].

Answer (score 5):

If you see a recurrence T(n) where one of the terms depends on the square root of the input size, it's often useful to define a new recurrence

> S(k) = T(2<sup>k</sup>)

since the resulting recurrence in k is often a lot easier to work with than the corresponding recurrence in n. In our case, we have

> S(k) = T(2<sup>k</sup>)
>
> = 2T(√(2<sup>k</sup>)) + 1
>
> = 2T(2<sup>k/2</sup>) + 1
>
> = 2S(k / 2) + 1

Notice that we now have a recurrence that matches the form expected by the master theorem (and that generally is much easier to work with than the original one). We can solve this recurrence to S(k) = Θ(k) via a number of different techniques.

Since we know that S(k) = Θ(k), what can we say about T(n)? Well, assuming that we're okay fudging things that aren't exact powers of two, we can say that T(n) ≈ S(lg n), since S(lg n) = T(2<sup>lg n</sup>) = T(n). Therefore, we get that

> T(n) = S(lg n) = Θ(lg n)

so T(n) = Θ(lg n).

Here's another way to arrive at this result that's less mathematical and more intuitive. Imagine the shape of the recursion tree that's formed by expanding the original recurrence T(n). At the top level, we have one call of size n doing 1 work. At the next level we have two calls of size <sup>2</sup>√n for a total of 2 work. At the level below that are four calls of size <sup>4</sup>√n for a total of 4 work. More generally, at level k, we have 2<sup>k</sup> calls each doing <sup>2<sup>k</sup></sup>√n work. The recursion terminates when n gets sufficiently small (say, n = 2), which happens at some level k. At that point, the total work done will have been

> 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + ... + 2<sup>k</sup> = 2(2<sup>k</sup>) - 1.

If we can solve for k, we'll know how much total work is done. Notice that the recursion stops when the input drops to size 2, which means that the k we want is one where <sup>2<sup>k</sup></sup>√n = 2. Solving for k, we see that

> <sup>2<sup>k</sup></sup>√n = 2
>
> n = 2<sup>2<sup>k</sup></sup>
>
> lg lg n = k

In general, if you see something shrinking by a square root factor, you should expect that [the number of iterations before the term drops to a constant is O(log log n)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16472012/what-would-cause-an-algorithm-to-have-olog-log-n-complexity/16472013#16472013). Therefore, the total work done is 2(2<sup>lg lg n</sup>) + 1 = 2 lg n - 1 = Θ(lg n), as before.

Comment: so it _doesn't_ depend on the termination condition?

Comment: @willywonkadailyblah In an asymptotic sense, assuming the termination condition is a fixed constant (both of when it triggers and what it evaluates to), no, it doesn't matter. It shaves at most a constant amount of work off the recursion tree or amplifies the total work done in the tree by a constant factor.

Comment: Thankyou very much... the solution is very helpful !

Comment: Hi, I' m not getting one thing,please if you could explain that how the series 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + ... + 2k is resulting to the value 2(2^k) - 1?

Comment: It's the sum of the geometric series 2^0 + 2^1 + 2^2 + ... + 2^k. It's worth committing the formula for the sum of a geometric series - and this series in particular - to memory.

Comment: @templatetypedef can you please ellaborate  2(2^(lg lg n)) + 1 = 2 lg n - 1 = Θ(lg n),

Comment: @Laura The key step here is (2^(lg lg n)) = lg n, which is true because 2^(lg x) = x for any x. Does that help?

Comment: Ahhh, i missed that , i know 3^(log base(2) n)=n^(log  base(2) 3) ..thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let us make the substitution [image]

Then

[image]

Where `N` is the number of terms before the series terminates.

But what is `N`? This depends on the answer to **amit**'s comment. Let assume that non-integer values are allowed for `n` in `T(n)`, and that `T` terminates (= 0) for `n < C`, for some constant `C > 1`.

Then we need

[image: ![enter image description here]

So the complexity is also dependent on `C`:

[image]

---

EDIT: Data to support my answer:

- graph of `T` against `log n`, `C = 1.5`:

[image]

- graph of `T` against `- log C`, `n = 2^64`:

[image]

As you can see, both are linear.

Answer (score 1):

Using Recursion tree method, you can solve as follows:
[follow this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osNJL.jpg)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Can you help me with a more difficult example using same recursion tree method? Specifically after I got 2^k-1. Here is recurrence:
T\left(n\right)=2T\left(\sqrt{n-1}+2\right)+1