# How do I prove that this algorithm is O(loglogn)

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

How do I prove that this algorithm is `O(loglogn)`

1. `i <-- 2`
2. **while** `i < n`
3. `i <-- i*i`

Well, I believe we should first start with `n / 2^k < 1`, but that will yield `O(logn)`. Any ideas?

**I want to look at this in a simple way**, what happends after one iteration, after two iterations, and after k iterations, I think this way I'll be able to understand better how to compute this correctly. What do you think about this approach? I'm new to this, so excuse me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16472012/what-would-cause-an-algorithm-to-have-olog-log-n-complexity

Comment: @FallAndLearn This is perfect. Thank you sir.!

Answer (score 0):

Let us use the name `A` for the presented algorithm. Let us further assume that the input variable is `n`.

Then, strictly speaking, `A` is not in the runtime complexity class `O(log log n)`. `A` must be in `(Omega)(n)`, i.e. in terms of runtime complexity, it is at least linear. Why? There is `i*i`, a multiplication that depends on `i` that depends on `n`. A naive multiplication approach might require quadratic runtime complexity. More sophisticated approaches will reduce the exponent, but not below linear in terms of `n`.
For the sake of completeness, the comparison `<`  is also a linear operation.

For the purpose of the question, we could assume that multiplication and comparison is done in constant time. Then, we can formulate the question: How often do we have to apply the constant time operations `>` and `*` until `A` terminates for a given `n`?
Simply speaking, the multiplication reduces the effort logarithmic and the iterative application leads to a further logarithmic reduce. How can we show this? Thankfully to the simple structure of `A`, we can transform `A` to an equation that we can solve directly.
`A` changes `i` to the power of 2 and does this repeatedly. Therefore, `A` calculates `2^(2^k)`. When is `2^(2^k) = n`? To solve this for `k`, we apply the logarithm (base 2) two times, i.e., with ignoring the bases, we get `k = log log n`. The `<` can be ignored due to the `O` notation.

To answer the very last part of the original question, we can also look at examples for each iteration. We can note the state of `i` at the end of the while loop body for each iteration of the while loop:

```
1: i =     4 =                                             2^2 = 2^(2^1)
2: i =    16 =     4*4 =                           (2^2)*(2^2) = 2^(2^2)
3: i =   256 =   16*16 =         4*4 = (2^2)*(2^2)*(2^2)*(2^2) = 2^(2^3)
4: i = 65536 = 256*256 = 16*16*16*16 =                     ... = 2^(2^4)
...
k: i =                                                     ... = 2^(2^k)
```