# Determining and analysis the big-O runtimes of these different loops

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

here is the simple code, i want to find out the time complexity of the code
i have already done analysis on it, my teacher told me that there is a mistake in it. i am not able to figure out where i am wrong. need a help in it. thanks

```
j = 2
while(j<n)
{
    k=j
    while(k < n) 
    {
        sum + = a[k]*b[k]
        k = k*k
    }
    k = log(n)
    j += log(k)
}
```

here what i got the answer

time complexity = O(n/loglogn).

i just want to know where i am wrong

Comment: Well, you've shown not much of analysis, rather an answer, so it's hard to guess where you are wrong

Answer (score 0):

You go from `2` to `n`, adding `log log n` to the accumulator each step, so you do indeed have `n / log log n` steps.

However, what is done per step? Each step, you go from `j` to `n`, multiplying the accumulator by itself each step. How many operations is that? **I'm not 100% sure**, but based on messing around a bit and on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16472013/15055), this seems to end up being `log log (n - j)` steps, or `log log n` for short.

So, `n / log log n` steps, doing `log log n` operations each step, gives you an `O(n / log log n * log log n)`, or `O(n)` algorithm.

---

Some experimentation seems to more or less bear this out (Python), although `n_ops` appears to flag a bit as `n` gets bigger:

```
import math

def doit(n):
    n_ops = 0

    j = 2
    while j < n:
        k = j
        while k < n:
            # sum + = a[k]*b[k]
            k = k*k
            n_ops += 1

        k = math.log(n, 2)
        j += math.log(k, 2)
        n_ops += 1

    return n_ops
```

Results:

```
>>> doit(100)
76
>>> doit(1000)
614
>>> doit(10000)
5389
>>> doit(100000)
49418
>>> doit(1000000)
463527
```

Comment: so what should be the time complexity of it according to you?

Comment: so its O(n) time complexity?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Let's see. The

```
k=j
while(k < n) 
{
    sum + = a[k]*b[k]
    k = k*k
}
```

bit takes what takes *j^(2^i)* to reach *n*. I.e. what *2^i* takes to reach *log_j(n)* which is *log_2(log_j(n))*. Now you have

```
j = 2
while(j<n)
{
    // stuff that takes log_2(log_j(n))
    j += log(log(n))
}
```

This would require `n/log(log(n))` of steps but those steps take different time. If they took equal time, you would be right. But instead you have to sum for {j from 2 to n/log(log(n))} log_2(log_j(n)) which is

```
sum for {j from 2 to n/log(log(n))} [log_2(log(n)) - log_2(log(j))]
```

which is not that simple. Well, at least, I think I've pointed where you are probably wrong, which was the question.