# Solving the recurrence T(n) = T(sqrt(n))+a

Tags: algorithm, recurrence, master-theorem

Hi I'm trying to solve the following equation with master theorem:

T(n) = a        ; for n<= 2

T(n) = T(√n) + a; else

As I found a similar equation ([Solving the recurrence T(n) = 2T(sqrt(n))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18098337/solving-the-recurrence-tn-2tsqrtn)) I'm wondering whether my solution is correct. I got T(n) = O(log log n). Is this correct for my equation above?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Big-O notation of T(sqrtn) + 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46512894/big-o-notation-of-tsqrtn-5)

Answer (score 1):

We can write down a table and look for a pattern:

```
n        T(n)
-        ----
2        a
4        T(2)  + a = 2a
16       T(4)  + a = 3a
256      T(16) + a = 4a
...
2^(2^k)  (k+1)a
```

We noticed `2 = 2^(2^0)`, `4 = 2^(2^1)`, `16 = 2^(2^2)`, and so on; by starting with two and squaring over and over, we get terms like `2^(2^k)` for which the corresponding values of `T(n)` are simply `(k+1)a`.

Given that `n = 2^(2^k)` and `T(n) = (k+1)a`, we can solve the first of these equations for `k` in terms of `n` and then substitute in the second. We get that `log log n = k` and so `T(n) = (1 + log log n)a`, which has the asymptotic bound you are after.

Technically, to complete this argument, we must note that `T(n)` is a monotonically non-decreasing function and so it is sufficient that we have shown the function is bounded in this way for this particular sequence of values of `n`. In general, a function might behave in such a way that the above method of analysis might be fooled into suggesting an inaccurate bound. For well-behaved functions this will not typically occur.