# What sorts of algorithmic patterns are polylogarithmic?

Tags: time-complexity, complexity-theory, space-complexity

What are the general attributes of an algorithm that cause a polylogarithmic term (e.g. `O(log log N)`) to be introduced into its time or space complexity?

I'm asking about general structural or behavioral properties, e.g. `O(N^3)` often corresponds to a triply-nested loop over all elements in a collection, or `O(log N)` often indicates that the algorithm could be modeled as a process of walking a path from the root to a leaf in a balanced tree.

Comment: There is good explanation about it in this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16472012/what-would-cause-an-algorithm-to-have-olog-log-n-complexity

Comment: @Naitonium thank you, very helpful! I'll close the question.

Comment: As a note, “polylogarithmic” usually means O(log^k n) = O((log n)^k) for some constant k. O(log log n) would be doubly-logarithmic rather then polylogarithmic.

Comment: @templatetypedef Right, I understand. That's why I gave `O(log log N)` only as an example. But the explanation linked by @Naitonium makes the point clear -- I can extrapolate to more than two levels based on that answer.

Comment: Oh, sorry, to clarify - (log n)^2 = (log n) * (log n) is an example of a polylogarithmic runtime. That is, polylogarithmic runtimes usually refer to runtimes made by multiplying logarithms together. On the other hand, log log n = log (log n) is typically not considered polylogarithmic, since it involves composing logarithms together rather than multiplying them.