# Big O complexity comparison of n^0.000001 and log(n) and many other

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

I have been trying to learn Big O complexity and I read multiple resources including the answer given by `dheeran` with a graph.
[Polynomial time and exponential time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317414/polynomial-time-and-exponential-time/34517541#34517541)

I have few doubts of my own and few new doubts are raised after reading the answer below because it was not descriptive and clear.

Note: n is large (in billions)

Q1. I have read that,  for any c > 0, log n is O(n^c).
My understanding of Big O is log n will always be less than n^c for any value of c.
So, check this example:

c = 0.000001

n = 1,000,000,000 i.e 1 billion

=> n^c = 1.00002072348

=> log(1 billion) = 9

So how come log n > n^c when log n is O(n^c)

Q.2 As mentioned in the answer, the order of increasing complexity is:

O(1),O(log n),O( (log n)^c ),O(n),O(n^2),O(n^c),O(c^n),O(n!)

If 0 < c < 1 eg. 0.001
Would the order change or still be:

-O( log n ),O( (log n)^c )

-O(n^c),O(c^n)

-O(n),O(c^n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here "in billions" means large enough. Hence, it depends on functions. To prove that you need an `n0`, and it can be `10^20` here, in your example.
Also, as `c` is a constant, you can choose `n0` base on the value of `c`. For example, if `c < 1`, you can choose `n0 = 10^{10/c}`. So, for all `n > n0`, `n^c` is greater than `log(n)`.

For the second question, definitely for `0 < c <= 1`, `c^n` is less than all those, as it goes to zero for bigger `n`! and `log(n)^c` is in `O(log(n))`. Therefore the order is:

```
c^n, 1, (log(n))^c, log(n), n^c, n, n^2, n!
```