# What is the fastest algorithm to calculate all factors of an integer number?

Tags: c, algorithm, numbers, factors

I have written this block of code but it is consuming lots of time to calculate...
Can you help me finding out an efficient way to do it?

```
int tag;
int* factors(int n)
{
    int a[1000000];
    for(int i=1;i<=n/2;i++)
        if(n%i==0)
            a[++tag]=i;
    a[++tag]=n;
    return(a);
}
```

This brute force method is very hefty in terms of complexity...
Is there any better feasible solution to this problem?

Comment: [Shor's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shor%27s_algorithm) :P

Comment: Returning a pointer to memory that gets deallocated when the function ends I see.

Comment: quick googling returns this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization

Comment: Just need to get a quantum computer, Mysticial...

Comment: How much time did you spend thinking about it?

Answer (score 12):

Until now no one has come up with a **much** faster algorithm. This doesn't necessarily have to mean there isn't any as on the other hand it also hasn't been proven that it is impossible to do it much faster.

One optimization you might want to take into account is that it's not necessary to search up to n/2 you can already stop when sqrt (n) is reached.

... and be sure to to choose a different storage location for your numbers if you really want to return a list of all candidates found as already mentioned in "chris" comment.

**EDIT:**

As I was adverted that there is a rather large variety of algorithms available that in terms of time complexity might run a little bit faster than the one you asked about it might be indicated to add a few more words than the short comment given above.

While besides the most obvious possibility to safe some computation time by just running the loop in steps of 2 after first dividing it down to an odd number there are still some other tricks available I didn't mention them as **substantially** faster in the answer given above.

The main reason that led to this decision is, that while for example cutting to number of iterations down by a factor of 2 seems like a big win to make in comparison to the expected growth in runtime with growing numbers a gain measured in terms of a constant becomes so small that in complexity theory there even won't be made any difference at all and both algorithms will be said to have (almost) the same time complexity.

Even if it was possible to get a **constant** gain of hundreds of a billion times the runtime of the original algorithm there still wouldn't be made any difference between both of them at all.

The bigger the numbers get the less influence any constant be it as big as you may ever be able to image plays in terms of runtime if it is also rapidly growing with the magnitude of the number you are adressing.

One very special barrier in terms of time complexity often regarded as the border between practically feasible and merely impossible is that of so called `polynomial` runtime.

This means nothing else than that even though the runtime might grow drastically with growing `n` it is still possible to describe this growth with a **constant** exponent `k`, such that the runtime is something around `n^k`.

On the other hand an algorithm without `polynomial` runtime can't be measured with any exponent how ever big you may want to make it.

To give an example why this difference might really matter at all let's take a look at two imaginary algorithms. The first one having polynomial runtime, say `n^10` and just another one say this one with runtime `n!`.

While it doesn't seem to bad for small numbers, let's say n is just 10 here algorithm one takes `10^10 = 10000000000` time units while with only `3628800` units our second algorithm seems to run even a lot faster.

The problem with our algorithm two is, that compared to algorithm one its runtime will grow dramatically faster. At `n=100` you get something like: `100000000000000000000` for algorithm one while it is already something like `93326215443944152681699238856266700490715968264381621468592963895217599993229915608941463976156518286253697920827223758251185210916864000000000000000000000000` for algorithm two.

Pushing frontiers even further with `n=1000` we end up with: algorithm one at `1000000000000000000000000000000` while our second algorithm will take something like `402387260077093773543702433923003985719374864210714632543799910429938512398629020592044208486969404800479988610197196058631666872994808558901323829669944590997424504087073759918823627727188732519779505950995276120874975462497043601418278094646496291056393887437886487337119181045825783647849977012476632889835955735432513185323958463075557409114262417474349347553428646576611667797396668820291207379143853719588249808126867838374559731746136085379534524221586593201928090878297308431392844403281231558611036976801357304216168747609675871348312025478589320767169132448426236131412508780208000261683151027341827977704784635868170164365024153691398281264810213092761244896359928705114964975419909342221566832572080821333186116811553615836546984046708975602900950537616475847728421889679646244945160765353408198901385442487984959953319101723355556602139450399736280750137837615307127761926849034352625200015888535147331611702103968175921510907788019393178114194545257223865541461062892187960223838971476088506276862967146674697562911234082439208160153780889893964518263243671616762179168909779911903754031274622289988005195444414282012187361745992642956581746628302955570299024324153181617210465832036786906117260158783520751516284225540265170483304226143974286933061690897968482590125458327168226458066526769958652682272807075781391858178889652208164348344825993266043367660176999612831860788386150279465955131156552036093988180612138558600301435694527224206344631797460594682573103790084024432438465657245014402821885252470935190620929023136493273497565513958720559654228749774011413346962715422845862377387538230483865688976461927383814900140767310446640259899490222221765904339901886018566526485061799702356193897017860040811889729918311021171229845901641921068884387121855646124960798722908519296819372388642614839657382291123125024186649353143970137428531926649875337218940694281434118520158014123344828015051399694290153483077644569099073152433278288269864602789864321139083506217095002597389863554277196742822248757586765752344220207573630569498825087968928162753848863396909959826280956121450994871701244516461260379029309120889086942028510640182154399457156805941872748998094254742173582401063677404595741785160829230135358081840096996372524230560855903700624271243416909004153690105933983835777939410970027753472000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`.

If you don't believe just calculate it yourself. The `bc` manual even contains an example of how to implement the factorial function.

But don't get dizzy while counting digits...
It might be interesting to know how many trailing zeroes we would have have to add to 10 to get the factor by which to multiply the age of our universe to get such a big span of time even if we measured in units of planck time. Unfortunately I don't know.

What's interesting about all that is the fact that until today there isn't any known algorithm that can perform factorization in `polynomial` time.

As it is not only an interesting field of research int itself the **practical** impossibility to factorize large integer numbers also plays an important role in the RSA public key encryption algorithm which is in widespread use today, so almost naturally there has already been a lot of resarch in this area.

Discovering algorithms that (without breaking the barrier already mentioned) run **sligthly** faster than the algorithm you supposed.

As "Jim Balter" alredy correctly annotated in his comment you might want to take a look at the referenced article (see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization#General-purpose) to take a look upon the methods others already came up with.

This article also mentioned by "Jim" might be another interesting resource: (see: [What is the fastest factorization algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267146/what-is-the-fastest-factorization-algorithm?rq=1))

Another interesting link to take a look upon might be the list of the RSA factoring challange winners of the past years to somehow get an idea where the border between feasible and almost impossible may lies today. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_Factoring_Challenge)

Comment: Okay...thats not a big problem..
I just forgot to make the storage location as global...

Comment: You can improve on the algorithm shown by only trying to divide by prime numbers — there are far fewer primes than there are composite numbers.

Comment: "Until now no one has come up with a much faster algorithm." -- Utter nonsense. a) This code divides by every integer, including even ones. b) It divides by values up to n/2 rather than sqrt(n). c) It doesn't divide out a factor once it finds one.

Comment: And beyond that there is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization#General-purpose ... So there are far faster algorithms than the OP's code.

Comment: okay maybe I should have stressed the **much** a little more. As at least regarding large numbers in terms of time complexity the usual notion is that the border line between anyhow feasible and practically almost impossible is P it was merely the fact that there isn't any algorithm running polynomial in time. I'll try to clarify that.

Comment: Look, *I* know about all that but the OP doesn't. The fact is that your answer is very poor ... the OP can get **much** faster results for numbers in a reasonable range.

Comment: BTW, if you look to the right under "Related", you will see a slew of far better and more sensible answers.

Comment: I strongly doubt your assumption really holds as the range of numbers adressed by OP is **reasonably** small enough to process the values just the way he intented. Even allowing a broader range than the one he adresses by passing UINT_MAX - taking a closer look you'll see he just passes an int! The runtime including process starting time got reported as this: `real m0.013s user0m0.008s sys 0m0.004s` which seems reasonable fast to me.

Comment: "that in complexity theory there even won't be made any difference at all and both algorithms will be said to have (almost) the same time complexity."  -- You don't really understand complexity theory or its significance. One can take a program with an O(n) algorithm and make it take a trillion times as long for all inputs and it's still O(n) -- that's a far cry from "there even won't be made any difference at all". There's only no difference at the limit of n -> infinity. And in any case, the OP's algoritm is O(n) but there are considerably faster algorithms with lower O.

Comment: Egads, you actually said this explicitly: "Even if it was possible to get a constant gain of hundreds of a billion times the runtime of the original algorithm there still wouldn't be made any difference between both of them at all" -- that's downright incoherent.

Comment: *shrug* don't see the incoherency here - it's just the same expressed in other words. I'm almost sure you didn't get it right: `...that's a far cry from "there even won't be made any difference at all". There's only no difference at the limit of n -> infinity"..` essentially what I was trying to explain that it's **only** the limit of n -> infinity that counts in complexity_theory at all. (see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_theory)

Comment: BTW.: while at it OPs algorithm can **never** **never** **never** **ever** be O(n). That would be a mere dream. In fact until now no one knows any O(n^k) method with any fixed k. The n to be taken into account here is the bitlength of the input not its magnitude. That's exactly why it's so hard to solve - the number of candidates to test doubles with every additional byte. Hence OPs algorithm is O(2^n)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27165/discussion-between-mikyra-and-jim-balter)

Comment: "don't see the incoherency here" -- right, there's no difference at all between two programs, one of which takes hundreds of billions of times longer to run than another. Because -- theory! Sorry, but it's theory misunderstood and misapplied. "The n to be taken into account here is the bitlength of the input not its magnitude. " -- The n is whatever we want it to be. Over and out.

Comment: "it's only the limit of n -> infinity that counts in complexity_theory at all. " -- Yes, but complexity theory isn't the only thing that counts; that's what you seem unable to understand. Taking hundreds of billions of times longer to execute does count. All the OP cares about is how long it takes the code to run for the n that the OP is using ... the question was not about complexity theory. Now I'm really done.

Comment: Why not? We're just littering the whole page if we continue like that. I know what you are talking about - but see it's the number of bits that gets counted as input the value encoded by the the bit pattern. What you are talking about is called **pseudo polynomial** complexity and there you are definately right OPs algorithm is for sure pseudo polynomial with complexity O(n). What's usually taken in account is the number of bits. That's exactly why RSA-keys are labeled according to the number of bits. Adding one bit doubles the number of candidates. That's what leads to exponential explosion.

Comment: *shrug* don't know - OP stated: "This brute force method is very hefty **in terms of complexity**... Is there any better feasible solution to this problem?" Thought he might be interested in complexity (theory) then.

Comment: Point taken about that quote. Sorry, my bad.