# How to optimize factorization code in Python?

Tags: python, optimization, factorization

I recently made a piece of code in Python that takes a user inputted number "n" and prints the prime factors of that number, including repeating primes. I got super excited cause I've been working on this for a while, but in reality it doesn't work so well.  Any n larger than about 500,000 takes so long to factor and I want to know if there is any way to optimize it.

```
import sys

def is_prime(n):
    if n < 2:
        return False
    if n == 2:
        return True
    if not n & 1:
        return False
    for x in range(3,int(n**0.5)+1,2):
        if n % x == 0:
            return False
    return True

def factors(n):
    n = int(n)
    factors = []
    test_numbers = []
    if is_prime(n) == True:
        print "%s is prime!" % n
    else:   
        for a in range(1,n+1):
            if is_prime(a) == True:
                test_numbers.append(a)
        while int(len(test_numbers)) > 0:
            mx = int(max(test_numbers))
            while n % mx == 0:
                n = n/mx
                factors.append(mx)
            else:
                test_numbers.remove(mx)
        print factors


n = raw_input("What number would you like to factorize?  ")
factors(n)
print

thing = raw_input("Press ENTER to continue.")
sys.exit()
```

Comment: Factorization is the hardest problem, on which the modern cryptographic security relies on. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267146/what-is-the-fastest-factorization-algorithm  for more detail answer

Comment: @SainathMotlakunta: I thought that was solving discrete logarithms.

Comment: This is better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com
See here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261841/can-i-post-questions-about-optimizing-code-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of improvements using some Pythonic idioms such as list comprehension:

```
import math
def factors(n):
    def is_prime(n):
        return not [m for m in xrange(2,int(math.sqrt(n))) if not n % m]

    primes = []
    test_numbers = xrange(2,n+1)
    test_number = 2
    while not primes and test_number in test_numbers:
        if not n % test_number and is_prime(test_number):
            primes = primes + [test_number] + factors(n/test_number)
        test_number += 1            
    return primes

n = raw_input("What number would you like to factorize? ")
n = int(n)
prime_factors = factors(n)
print prime_factors
```

It will be fast or slow depending on how many factors `n` has (slowest if `n` is prime, fastest if it has lots of small prime factors).

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is slow because it does too much work. There is no need to calculate the primes less then *n*, as your `for` loop does. And there is no need to separately test *n* for primality, because the algorithm will determine that itself. Here is a simple program to factor integers by trial division:

```
>>> def factors(n):
...     f, fs = 2, []
...     while f * f <= n:
...        while n % f == 0:
...            fs.append(f)
...            n /= f
...        f += 1
...     if n > 1: fs.append(n)
...     return fs
... 
>>> factors(997)
[997]
>>> factors(13290059)
[3119, 4261]
>>> factors(1234098760912343)
[67, 103, 184117, 971279]
```

Notice that 997 is determined to be prime. Notice too that the factors of a large number are calculated instantly, but don't count on that; trial division has a time complexity of O(sqrt(*n*)), and is slow when the factors of *n* are large.

There are better ways to factor integers. There are even better ways to factor integers by trial division. But that should be enough to get you started.