# How can I find integers in a range which are sums of max. 4 perfect square numbers in Python?

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, math

I have this mathematical, Python problem, where I have to find all numbers in a range which are the sum of maximum 4 square numbers. I can't think about a working algorithm, with my basic knowledge. Can you help me out with the algorithm, or an idea of where to start? I'm not asking for the code. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should head to https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What  do  you mean by "maximum square numbers"? A famous theorem in number theory states that *any* positive integer equals the sum of at most four squares of positive integers. So according to the usual meaning of your words, the entire range satisfies your criterion (at least the nonnegative part of it).

Comment: Maybe he needs to identify these numbers?

Comment: This is the solution, I needed to find all numbers in this range which can be defined as a sum of max. 4 perfect squares. So the output is the whole range, and that was the good solution. Thanks for everyone, have a nice day!

Comment: See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41556521/5459839) on how to generate those four squares.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [Lagrange theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_four-square_theorem), you can return the whole positive range because

> every natural number can be represented as the sum of four integer
>   squares.

It means that the algorithm can be written as:

```
def my_algorithm(integer_range):
    return [i for i in integer_range if i >= 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_four-square_theorem) link out.

This wikipedia page will solve your problem!

Basically, all whole numbers can be represented as a sum of 4 perfect squares.