# Find the number of bits in the product of a multiplication without knowing one of the factors

Tags: algorithm, binary, numbers, bit, multiplication

Suppose I have some odd number N with more than 1000 bits and I want to multiply it by some number H so that their product results in a number in which all its bits are 1. For example:

```
  N = 0b1101
  H = 0b100111011
N*H = 0b111111111111
```

Taking this condition into consideration, how do I find the length of NH without knowing H?

Comment: How do you know that such a number even exists?

Comment: Euler's theorem establishes that there exists some k such that 2^k = 1 mod N. Therefore, 2^k - 1 is a multiple of N.

Comment: You can find the prime factorization of N, figure out M the number of integers mod N that are relatively prime to it, factor M, then search for the smallest factor k of M with 2^k = 1 mod N. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267146/what-is-the-fastest-integer-factorization-algorithm for factorization algorithms.

Comment: @Spektre You don't even need to do the dividing. I'll add my comment as a solution in an hour or so.

Answer (score 1):

First, assume we have some sort of fast factorization algorithm. [What is the fastest integer factorization algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267146/what-is-the-fastest-integer-factorization-algorithm) discusses a few.

In Python, we can get a decent implementation from [primefac](https://pypi.org/project/primefac/).

Next. As you point out, we're looking for the first `k` such that `2**k` is `1 mod N`. Euler's theorem says that this will be a divisor of [Euler's totient function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TotientFunction.html). So let's first be able to calculate the totient function, in fully factored form.

```
from primefac import primefac

def factored_totient (n):
    answer = []
    last_p = 0
    for p in primefac(n):
        if p == last_p:
            answer.append(p)
        else:
            last_p = p
            for q in primefac(p-1):
                answer.append(q)
    return sorted(answer)
```

Next, here is a helper function that I'll use to calculate `2^k mod n`, and then the algorithm.

```
def n_pow_m_mod_k (n, m, k):
    answer = 1
    cur_pow = n
    while 0 < m:
        if 1 == m % 2:
            answer = (answer * cur_pow) % k
        cur_pow = (cur_pow * cur_pow) % k
        m = m // 2
    return answer

def bits_puzzle (n):
    if 0 == n % 2:
        return None
    ft = factored_totient(n)
    answer = 1
    for p in ft:
        answer *= p
    last_failed_p = 0
    for p in ft:
        if p != last_failed_p:
            factor = answer // p
            if 1 == n_pow_m_mod_k(2, factor, n):
                answer = factor
            else:
                last_failed_p = p
    return answer
```

And you can test it out with a few small values.

```
for n in (0b10101, 0b10, 0b1101):
    print((n, bin(n), bits_puzzle(n)))
```

I also tried testing it out on numbers of the size that you wanted. Unfortunately, factoring a random 1000 bit number is very hard. On a typical run in a minute or so it had a bunch of factors adding up to about 100 bits, and was now stuck trying to factor a 900 bit number with no small factors. As [Integer Factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization) points out, that's in the range of factorization problems usable in cryptography. Assuming that the last number is a semi-prime, it is probably on the order of tens to hundreds of thousands of years of computation time with specialized distributed algorithms.

---

First, here is how to generate some timings for my code with reasonably large numbers.

```
from random import randint
import time
for i in range(20):
    n = 0
    while n % 2 == 0:
        n = randint(2**90, 2**150)
    print("n:", hex(n))
    start = time.time_ns()
    print("k:", bits_puzzle(n))
    elapsed = time.time_ns() - start
    print(elapsed / 10**9, "s")
    print("")
```

Note that I'm calling it `k` because `nh` is actually `2^k - 1`.

Here is a random run. As you see, the timing varies a lot, and it varies based on how hard the factorization problem was. I have no reason to believe that I found the upper hardness of this problem.

```
n: 0x27db0e0e56f4f21a7ea5308e43dce23ccfcd1
k: 1735959737225222027371704646937187307096940
0.0603292 s

n: 0x74e81db07a5180b790b823074e43670fc0f1
k: 84039869941836137391452330898072464580
80.1900925 s

n: 0x5fa38f8665313dab0dac4255be076a8e723ad
k: 162562241923766609717203365262967874113340
0.5413121 s

n: 0x46f00c516d5c4de437d204eae06192258e617
k: 476814060930400388303839367656415214780
0.2139004 s

n: 0x1ebfebb3068b37ddbd15ab128388b6685352d3
k: 48981500492109467784235089287477723783729004
1.4829496 s

n: 0x1082c5079cdc395997f420d188945a00884511
k: 1839085993569181822835159135725482047446740
0.0020689 s

n: 0x2c2bc8611b5eb020d7b6f25e1b85f399f2abdb
k: 1520004250451326440651076810086872852941980
0.0861389 s

n: 0x7cb6323b878d2c20f31c74ea0a66ae5e5e243
k: 942256584797380357284318652447757100
37.4464112 s

n: 0x18dba10ae63800528e4012d19812854a1afd8d
k: 6599407970546479882300913684964741047176926
0.2023561 s

n: 0xc92abb980f7b941d524206e6d5eef9e5a8acb
k: 1377581386603846304202470437856149522940
9.9058992 s

n: 0x3589d7b4123c499ce065f2a6aeda64416485c9
k: 4735611477602199137624085295217020618085220
22.61243 s

n: 0x373d36fa8fce048c537c21fdf03305e4a33c19
k: 17109354767394410817768204498763288554176508
0.0866174 s

n: 0x1789cdb97ff0837c13513f82dcc6eed541639b
k: 18182635322784274674659015110917690593592
0.0065424 s

n: 0x1cfae59267438138b1f508bab4c53bce96adf9
k: 2928358186446655134738594666585456929325204
0.0130819 s

n: 0x25ff5575fc782dcf6f384f895aaf526c06fff7
k: 423666700301643167529079302107722180633022012
0.3127472 s

n: 0x2a69dc1d0387dd1df71a36cc0babb4042366c1
k: 8565445990078797248618253447955492323068820
0.0114316 s

n: 0x3594cc43cac1ffa05645213b99b789dcf18f07
k: 33191711680414297856278886084996455227266286
0.318079 s

n: 0x330d985c6dad53b6a8356a527b3ac122aade5f
k: 12176709183010991130747468517001563231921080
0.0700982 s

n: 0x44e5c7b41b4e38aa1ca100872229b92803887
k: 3427881600113681859887602966536998248715490
88.2850662 s

n: 0x34f1b34377f624a83fb3aa5cbd19a71a15beb
k: 169959588434779552651827461841241215729186
0.0299057 s
```

(I actually ran it again, and the following demonstrated that it can be slower.)

```
n: 0x36ab2f75683f3cd0d818125c7ea43a3e37ced5
k: 26050265403255744008775446989740158983956
1464.2803555 s
```

So half an hour.

---

And now to explain my "broke cryptography" comment.

I've shown how to use factoring to solve this problem. Now let's show how this problem can solve the key problem behind RSA.

The fundamental problem in RSA is factoring a large semiprime `n = p*q` where `p` and `q` are both large primes. Because we have lots of special case factoring algorithms, we have lots of rules on what `p` and `q` should be. Let the cryptographers worry about that. I'll just assume that they are both big, `p < q < p^k` for some relatively small integer `k`. (eg 3.)

Suppose further that `0 < ε`. Then (waving my hands a bit) I believe that the following can all be proven to be very likely  for sufficiently large `n` (meaning that by randomly picking `n` in a large enough range with the given properties, we can make the probability of all of these arbitrarily close to 1):

1. Let `s` be the smallest integer such that `p` divides `2^s -1`. By Euler's theorem, `s` divides `p-1`.
2. Also (this is where I'm waving my hands), with high likelihood `p^ε < s`.
3. Let `t` be the smallest integer such that `q` divides `2^t -1`. By Euler's theorem, `t` divides `q-1`.
4. Waving my hands in the same was as step 2, with high likelihood, `p^ε < t`.
5. With high likelihood, `gcd(p-1, q-1) < p^ε`.
6. Since `gcd(s, t)` is a common divisor of `p-1` and `q-1`, with high likelihood, `gcd(s, t) < p^ε`.

If all that is shown, then `k`, the smallest number such that `2^k-1` is divisible by `n`, must be divisible by:

s*t/gcd(s, t)
> (p/p^ε) * (q/p^ε) / p^ε = p * q / p^3ε = n / p^3ε

Now if, say, `ε < 1/4`, that means that, with very high probability, `p + q < k`.

Why does this matter?

It matters because we have `n = p*q`. And we know that `k` divides `(p-1)*(q-1) = p*q - p - q + 1`. Using `//` for integer division, let's think about what `k * (n//k)` will be. It must be the largest multiple of  `k` that is less than or equal to `n`. We know that `p*q - p - q + 1` is a possible multiple in that range. And because `p+q < k`, there can't be any between that and `n`.

**THEREFORE** for large semiprimes `n` of interest for RSA, with very high likelihood `n - 1 - k * (n//k) = p + q`.

But if `p + q = a` and `p*q = n`,

```
n = p * q
  = p * (a - p)
  = a*p - p^2
```

And so `p` is a root of

```
p^2 - a*p + n = 0
```

We can solve for this by the quadratic formula. And this allows us to factor the semiprimes that are of interest for RSA cryptography.

Therefore a solution of your problem that is significantly more efficient than the division approach, allows us to solve the problem that RSA encryption is based on. It seems inherently unlikely to me that we'll accidentally solve that problem. And therefore I think that your problem will turn out to be as hard as division.

Sorry.

Comment: This is a solution but it is not viable because N has more than 1000 bits, so it is practically impossible to factor.

Comment: I was wondering if some kind of matrix system could solve this problem, but I have no idea.

Comment: @user1240174 I had an Idea and it looks like its working much much better than our approaches we tried ... had added an answer. But still if `n` bitwidth is `1000+` bits it will take a long time (but its in minutes/hours instead of centuries)

Comment: @user1240174 I just updated my answer with reasons to believe that it really is intrinsically hard, and no magic approach will suffice.

Comment: @btilly This makes a lot of sense, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Well I tested partial prime decomposition and bruteforce division performance in C++ and both are very similar (just 3% difference in favor to prime decomposition but at cost of huge time and space for its precomputation making it worthless) so with brute force I could get up to ~2000 bits of `n*h` which is too few so this is not good approach. Here my C++ implementation:

```cpp
int compute0(uint<_max_words> &n)   // naive bruteforce division
    {
    int nh_bits;
    uint<_max_words> h,nh;
    for (nh_bits=1,nh=1;nh<n;nh<<=1,nh|=1,nh_bits++);
    for (;;nh<<=1,nh|=1,nh_bits++)
        {
        h=nh%n;
        if (!h){ h=nh/n; break; }
        if (nh.a[0]==0xFFFFFFFF){ h=0; nh=0; break; }
        }
    return nh_bits;
    }
```

Where `uint<_max_words>` is my big unsigned int class (you can use any BigInt lib)...

After some thinking It occurred to me to do a "binary long division" `nh/n`  where on non zero  remainder we just add one bit to `nh` and continue the division reusing already computed values until zero remainder occurs...

this ease up the stuff **a lot** at the cost that we no longer know `h` (well it can be computed too at relatively small cost) but that is OK as we do not want it anyway...

Here simple C++ implementation:

```cpp
int compute1(uint<_max_words> &n) // continuous binary long division
    {
    int nh_bits;
    uint<_max_words> nh;
    for (nh_bits=1,nh=1;nh<n;nh<<=1,nh|=1,nh_bits++);
    for (;;nh<<=1,nh|=1,nh_bits++)
        {
        if (nh>=n) nh-=n;                // long division
        if (nh.iszero()) break;          // no remainder?
        if (nh_bits>=10000000) return 0; // result too big
        }
    return nh_bits;
    }
```

the speed difference is:

```
n="13453h"
bitwidth used for computation: 1700

[2061.415 ms] n: 17 , nh: 1688 // brute force
[   2.067 ms] n: 17 , nh: 1688 // binary long division
```

here another results (just the binary long division hence the smaller bitwidth to compare performance based on used bitwidth arithmetics):

```
bitwidth used for computation: 64
n="12345654321h";   
[1327.825 ms] n: 41 , nh: 8947848
        
bitwidth used for computation: 128
n="12345654321h";   
[2076.532 ms] n: 41 , nh: 8947848

bitwidth used for computation: 256
n="12345654321h";   
[2704.338 ms] n: 41 , nh: 8947848

bitwidth used for computation: 1024
n="12345654321h";   
[7481.255 ms] n: 41 , nh: 8947848
```

looks like the bitwidth used dependency is slightly sub-linear...

So if the `nh` bitwidth is small enough (milions of bits) then this approach is still fast enough. However if its not or there is no solution the stuff will hang up ... unless detection or max limit is added. Note that this algo need to use just arithmetics that can hold `n` which makes this even more fast.

Comment: My python solution does not need precomputation and runs in 1/7 of the time for your binary division algorithm. I'm pretty sure on other grounds that if your algorithm is fast enough, then you've broken cryptography. But I'll update my post with that later.

Comment: @btilly can you provide some "big" input / output for comparison ... I mean `n` and `bits(n*h)` along with time needed for computation.

Comment: If N is more than 1000 bits, then N will be greater than 2^1000 and NH will be almost 2^(2^1000).

Comment: It is necessary to find the bitwidth without actually calculating the value of N*H.

Comment: @Spektre I updated my post with some examples with `n` around 150 bits. And an explanation of what I meant by "broken cryptography". (I actually meant, "Would be able to break RSA encryption with decent probability.")