# Most Efficient Way to Find All the Factors of a Number?

Tags: swift, algorithm, performance

> **Disclaimer**: There are similar questions to this one on SO, *however*
>   they all either don't address the efficiency of an algorithm or are
>   written in a different language. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800193/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-of-finding-all-the-factors-of-a-number-in-python/) which talks
>   about efficiency in **python** and see if it helps you answer my question.

So I need the **most** efficient way to find all of the factors of any given number that works quickly with very large numbers. I already have several iterations of code that works but takes a very long time to process numbers with more than 6 characters.

> Edit: upon request here are some of my non-efficient ways of doing this (error-checking left out for clarity)

**Really messy**:

```
    @IBAction func findFactorsButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if let _ = textField.text, !textField.text!.isEmpty {
        counter = 1
        factors = []
        repeat {
            counter += 1
            if Int(textField.text!)! % counter == 0 {
                factors.append(String(counter))
            } else {
                continue
            }
        } while counter != Int(textField.text!)
        factors.removeLast()
        outputLabel.text = factors.joined(separator: ", ")

    } else {
        outputLabel.text = ""
    }
}
```

**Less messy solution (playground):**

```
func calculateFactors(n: Int) -> String {
    var result: String = ""
    for i in 1...n {
        guard n % i == 0  else {continue}
        result += i == 1 ? "1" : ", \(i)"
    }
    print(result)
    return result
}
```

Comment: Could you show us those iterations, listed in order of performance best to last?

Comment: Efficient for factoring a single number? Or many? In the latter case you would pre-compute a list of primes. In what range are the numbers?

Comment: Here https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/166342/35991 is an implementation which should be faster than yours.

Comment: Finding the factors of a single number. **Not** prime factors.

Comment: Is there *any* upper limit on the numbers you are working with?

Comment: 8 characters is the limit

Comment: How to efficiently find all factors is an algorithm question that has little to do with any specific programming language, and @SamHarwell’s answer to that question (quoted here by @ColGraff) lists all the best algorithms for solving this problem. There was no Swift code in your question when I closed it. Since you added some code, I have reopened the question.

Comment: I am a bit late here but I read "playground". Keep in mind that every line of code in the main playground page runs very slow. There are reasons for this. If you need code to be fast?  use swift packages executables https://www.fivestars.blog/code/ultimate-guide-swift-executables.html or put the code to be executed in the Source folder of the playgrounds. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55303942/9497800

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most Python methods in the referenced Q&A [What is the most efficient way of finding all the factors of a number in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800193/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-of-finding-all-the-factors-of-a-number-in-python)  use the fact that
factors of `n` come in pairs: if `i` is a factor then `n/i` is another
factor. Therefore it is sufficient to test factors up to the square root
of the given number.

Here is a possible implementation in Swift:

```
func factors(of n: Int) -> [Int] {
    precondition(n > 0, "n must be positive")
    let sqrtn = Int(Double(n).squareRoot())
    var factors: [Int] = []
    factors.reserveCapacity(2 * sqrtn)
    for i in 1...sqrtn {
        if n % i == 0 {
            factors.append(i)
        }
    }
    var j = factors.count - 1
    if factors[j] * factors[j] == n {
        j -= 1
    }
    while j >= 0 {
        factors.append(n / factors[j])
        j -= 1
    }
    return factors
}
```

Remarks:

- `reserveCapacity` is used to avoid array reallocations.
- All factors in the range `1...sqrtn` are determined first,
  then the corresponding factors `n/i` are appended in reverse order,
  so that all factors are in increasing order.
- Special care must be taken that for perfect squares, `sqrt(n)` is
  not listed twice.

For numbers with up to 8 decimal digits, at most 9,999 trial
divisions are needed. Example
(on a 1.2 GHz Intel Core m5 MacBook, compiled in Release mode):

```
let start = Date()
let f = factors(of: 99999999)
print("Time:", Date().timeIntervalSince(start) * 1000, "ms")
print("Factors:", f)
```

Output:

```
Time: 0.227034091949463 ms
Factors: [1, 3, 9, 11, 33, 73, 99, 101, 137, 219, 303, 411, 657, 803, 909, 1111, 1233, 1507, 2409, 3333, 4521, 7227, 7373, 9999, 10001, 13563, 13837, 22119, 30003, 41511, 66357, 81103, 90009, 110011, 124533, 152207, 243309, 330033, 456621, 729927, 990099, 1010101, 1369863, 3030303, 9090909, 11111111, 33333333, 99999999]
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer Martin, it works way more efficiently than my own previous version

Answer (score 3):

It all depends on your numbers. Here is a great [summary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1877335/887210):

> "How big are your numbers?" determines the method to use:
>
> - Less than 2^16 or so: Lookup table.
> - Less than 2^70 or so: <strike>[Sieve of Atkin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Atkin). This is an optimized version of the more well known [Sieve of
>     Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).</strike> **Edit:** [Richard Brent's modification](http://wwwmaths.anu.edu.au/~brent/pub/pub051.html)
>     of [Pollard's rho algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm) may be better in this case.
> - Less than 10^50: [Lenstra elliptic curve factorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra_elliptic_curve_factorization)
> - Less than 10^100: [Quadratic Sieve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_sieve)
> - More than 10^100: [General Number Field Sieve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_number_field_sieve)

So it all becomes a matter of picking algorithms and implementing them in Swift. Since you're saying you need numbers with "6 characters" that implies they are around 2^17 or so. So it's option 2 in that list: Sieve of Atkin or the modification of Pollard's rho.

Comment: So can you share with me the implementation of the modified Pollard's Rho Algorithm in swift?

Comment: I don't have an implementation in Swift, you'll have to implement it or find it. The link gives the general algorithm, it should be relatively easy to code it in Swift.