# Recursive Algorithm Is Much Slower in Playgrounds (1 minute) Than Xcode (0.1 seconds)

Tags: swift, recursion, swift-playground

I have code to solve a sudoku board using a recursive algorithm.

The problem is that, when this code is run in Xcode, it solves the algorithm in 0.1 seconds, and when it is run in playgrounds, where I need it, it takes almost one minute.

When run in iPad, it takes about 30 seconds, but still obviously nowhere near the time it takes in xcode.

Any help or ideas would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Never measure performance in a Playground, since it doesn't represent real-world results due to compilation optimization differences.

Comment: I know, but for this project, I need it to be run in a playground. Is there anyway I could speed it up?

Comment: Yes. Don't use recursion. Or move the recursion out of the playground into Sources.

Comment: Ok, I will add it to the sources

Comment: Every recursive algorithm can be converted into an iterative algorithm. that doesn't suggest brute force.

Comment: @RobNapier why do you think that recursion slowdown playgrounds compared to iterative approach?

Comment: @ManWithBear You make an excellent point. Playgrounds will likely cause the same problem due to printing. I said this because I was thinking about TCO in an optimized build (but I actually don't know that Swift does any TCO yet).

Comment: @RobNapier https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24023580/does-swift-implement-tail-call-optimization-and-in-mutual-recursion-case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Playground try to get result of each your operation and print it out (repl style)
2. It just slow and laggy by itself
3. In Xcode you can compile your code with additional optimization that speedup your code a lot (e. g. [Swift Beta performance: sorting arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24101718/swift-beta-performance-sorting-arrays))

Source files compiles as separate module, so don't forget about `public/open` access modifiers.
To create source files:
[image]

Comment: I know, but I need this project to be done in playgrounds. Is there a way I can speed it up?

Comment: @NikolasIoannou you can try move all your logic code inside source files, then here will be less printings and it should be faster

Comment: How can I create a source file? Thank you for helping! Do I just create a swift file in sources?

Comment: YES! That worked, thank you so much. I will accept it in 2 minutes when available.

Comment: @NikolasIoannou just for info, how fast it now?